# приложение на kivimd вылетает при запуске

Tags: python, buildozer

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("appscreen.kv")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### appscreen.kv

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "эк1 Аккаунты"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state ("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "эк2 Добавить аккаунт"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state ("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "эк3 Удалить невалидные ак."
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state ("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 3"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "эк4 Старт рассылки"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state ("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 4"
            
    Screen:
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {"top":1}
            elevation: 10
            title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        MDNavigationLayout:
            x:toolbar.height
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                # содержимое экрана 1
                Screen:
                    name: "scr 1"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "открыт экран 1"
                        haling: "center"
                # содержимое экрана 2
                Screen:
                    name: "scr 2"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "открыт экран 2"
                        haling: "center"
                # содержимое экрана 3
                Screen:
                    name: "scr 3"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "открыт экран 3"
                        haling: "center"
                # содержимое экрана 4
                Screen:
                    name: "scr 4"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "открыт экран 4"
                        haling: "center"
            
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

### Версии которые я использую

1. Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64-bit
2. Python 3.10.12
3. Cython version 0.29.33
4. Kivy 2.2.1
5. Buildozer 1.5.1.dev0
6. openjdk 11.0.21

### Файл buildozer.spec

```
1)osx.kivy_version = 2.2.1
2)requirements = python3,kivy==2.2.1,kivymd
```

### логи ошибок при запуске приложения

```
[WARNING] [Base] Unknown <android> provider
```

[image: все логи]

Comment: Прошу вас убрать принтскрин из вопроса. Лучше добавить текстом ошибки, которые у вас появляются и в вопросе можно указать ещё раз конкретно вопрос,  так как тема вопроса  не должна быть вопросом (каламбур).

Comment: Вообще то я и так текстом написал а скрин это просто для общего понимания в скрине больше ничего полезного нету что ты придрался вообще не понимаю ВОТ - [WARNING] [Base] Unknown <android> provider ВИДИШЬ?

Comment: Ведите себя воспитанно! И не надо тыкать незнакомым людям.

Comment: простите за моё поведение с уважением ко всем